# Aurora serverless option doesn't show up as an option while creating the RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Aurora serverless option doesn't show up in middle-east region (Bahrain) but it shows up in other areas. Also, I checked and made sure that Aurora serverless is available in this region

[image]

[image: Choosing Aurora with only provisioned type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aurora Serverless v1 is not available in Middle East (Bahrain) region.

[image]

---

Reference:

[Supported features in Amazon Aurora by AWS Region and Aurora DB engine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraFeaturesRegionsDBEngines.grids.html#Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.Serverless)